# How to delete a latest branch/tag for a repository in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i am developing one project in development server. This is first version for this entire project. So after i done with development, i committed the code and i updated my local repository.

```
url: svn+ssh://home/projects/application_name
```

Once it's done i used branch/tag option and created new branch with tag 1.1.0. The url for this new branch is below one.

```
url: svn+ssh://home/projects/application_name_1.1.0
```

Now i checked out this new branch code in test server for testing. I got some errors so i ned to resolve them. But i can create new branch/tag like i did previously after i resolved errors in dev server and again i can move the new branch code to test server.

What i want to know is how can i delete 1.1.0 branch permanently from svn so that i can create new branch again with 1.1.0 name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to remove the branch "permanently". You can remove it with a regular commit and create a new branch as you did before.

```
svn rm svn+ssh://home/projects/application_name_1.1.0
svn cp svn+ssh://home/projects/application_name \
    svn+ssh://home/projects/application_name_1.1.0
```